# jquery for bootstrap select validation

Tags: javascript, php, twitter-bootstrap-3

**Bootstrap 3 validation is not work properly in select**. `html code is`

```
<div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label">Select std.<span class="f_req">*</span></label>
    <div class="controls">
       <select name="std" class="span5">
          <option value="1">1</option>
          <option value="2">2</option>
          <option value="3">3</option>
          <option value="4">4</option>
          <option value="5">5</option>
       </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

And javascript is  **`rules: { std: { required : true } }`**
Please help me.. thanks in advance